# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Tribe' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following some online examples for getting to grips with ggplot2 in R. As part of this I am trying to add in the automatic coloring of series using pre-defined color schemes.

The following code will work:

```
ggplot(subset(homes, STATE %in% c("MA","TX"))) + geom_point(aes_string(x="Date", y="Home.Value"))
```

However, when I add the color option:

```
ggplot(subset(homes, STATE %in% c("MA","TX"))) + geom_point(aes_string(x="Date", y="Home.Value"), color=State)
```

I get the error: **"Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint,  : 
  object 'State' not found"**

I have also tried 'Tribe' and 'cp1' with no luck and the same error message. Is there anything I need to do to bring the auto color options into the software so the objects are recognised?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the colour of your points to vary by the variable `state`, so it should be inside the `aes`:

```
 geom_point(aes(colour = State))
```

Anything outside of the `aes` is constant, so, `colour=red` or `size=2`.

Comment: Thanks. I amended the code to:    ggplot(subset(homes, STATE %in% c("MA","TX"))) + geom_point(aes_string(x="Date", y="Home.Value", color = State)). I now get a new error: "Error in aes_string(x = "Date", y = "Home.Value", color = State) :  object 'State' not found". Is there still something wrong in there?

Comment: I used aes, you are using aes_string, so try putting `state` in quotes: `"state"`

Comment: Doing that gives the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'State' not found". If I change the 'aes_string' to 'aes' and removed the quotes around the state I get the same error as above. so my full code would be **ggplot(subset(homes, STATE %in% c("MA","TX"))) + geom_point(aes(x="Date", y="Home.Value", color = State))** which gives the error at the top of this comment.

Comment: Remove the quotes from Data and Home.Value. Also should it be STATE?

Comment: And its working! Thanks so much for your help! This worked: **ggplot(subset(homes, STATE %in% c("MA","TX"))) + geom_point(aes(x=Date, y=Home.Value, color = STATE))**